# SDL_GetRelativeMouseState strange behaviour

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have an application in SDL 2.0.3 that enters relative mouse mode before entering the main game loop. In addition, function `mouse_input` is called in each step:

```
int mdltx = 0, mdlty = 0;

void mouse_input () {
    auto r = SDL_GetRelativeMouseState(&mdltx, &mdlty);

    if (mdltx != 0 || mdlty != 0)
        cout << "(" << mdltx << "," << mdlty << ")" << endl;

    // Update mouse key presses
    mpul = !!(r&SDL_BUTTON(1)) | ((!!(r&SDL_BUTTON(3)))<<1);
}
```

According to the [documentation of `SDL_GetRelativeMouseState`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetRelativeMouseState?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryMouse%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29):

> (...) **x** and **y** are set to the mouse deltas since the last call to SDL_GetRelativeMouseState() or since event initialization.

I've added the output lines for debugging purposes, because the resulting effect in the application was very awkward. It turns out that each time I move the mouse (and only when I move it), the console prints values in an unreasonable range. Below is a sample from doing simple mouse movements. The affected axis seems correct (moving horizontally will set `mdlty` to 0 and moving vertically will set `mdltx` to 0), but the numbers can get much higher than the screen resolution, and all of them are positive, regardless of the direction I move the mouse.

---

> (342,216)
>
> (47290,0)
>
> (23696,0)
>
> (23730,0)
>
> (23764,0)
>
> (23799,0)
>
> (71190,0)
>
> (117970,83397)
>
> (23491,41802)
>
> (23457,0)
>
> (23423,83811)
>
> (0,41871)
>
> (23389,208322)
>
> (23355,82847)
>
> (0,41320)
>
> (46812,0)

---

I have been looking around the web for people having the same problem, without any success.
Also note that this application was previously made for SDL 1, relying on `SDL_GetMouseState` and `SDL_WarpMouse`, but the latter function does not seem to do anything in some platforms. I'm working on the application under an Arch Linux + LXDE installation, which seems to simply ignore the mouse warp. This is the same machine where this other strange behaviour is happening.

The question is: why is this happening and how can I fix it with compatibility in mind, while keeping the advantages of having relative mouse mode? I even wonder if it could be an issue within SDL itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else struggling with this problem, it might help to set:

```
SDL_SetHintWithPriority(SDL_HINT_MOUSE_RELATIVE_MODE_WARP, "1", SDL_HINT_OVERRIDE);
SDL_SetRelativeMouseMode(SDL_TRUE);
```

This seems to give you relative mouse-output, where the center of the screen is (0,0).

However for me it doesn't currently reset the Cursor-coordinates properly, so while every frame resets this to (0,0), it jumps straight to the previous coord += movement.

This is a lot better than the alternative though, it seems.

Answer (score 1):

The same code is working in a different machine, so this seems to be a bug. And it seems that some people found it too, with a broader range of misbehaviours than the one mentioned.
https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2150